# SSIS - Data Transfer from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: ssis

I want to transfer data from SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2012 database. Is it possible with SSIS?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible and I had seen the same happening in one of my companies project. They both are Microsoft product and I don't see any reason why Microsoft won't recommend up gradation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SSIS can use SQL Server 2000 as a data source and SQL Server 2012 as a destination.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read from almost any source and write to almost any destination